# Hibernate EC2 instance : Does it really freezes OS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, operating-system

So, I was trying EC2 Hibernate feature and I understood what is happening behind the scenes:-

**"Contents of ram are written to EBS Volume and the instance is stopped".**

**"The hibernation freezes all of the processes saves the contents of the RAM to the Amazon EBS root volume, and then performs a regular shutdown."[AWS hibernate DOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html)**

However, I tried running a command using ssh.

```
before hibernation 

uptime // value was something say 1 min

after hibernation 

uptime // value was increased say 4 min
```

SO my question is; if uptime value is changing(***in the case of stop-hibernate state***); does that mean OS is not frozen, is it still running? How different is it from a ***regular shutdown***?

Comment: How long was it hibernated in between?

Comment: For around 5-6 minutes

Comment: The OS would definitely _not_ be running, since the EC2 instance is stopped. However, the `uptime` value might be impacted by how the operating system calculates it. For example, it might record the time that the machine was started, and simply print the time difference from then to now. Or, it might tick-over every second.

Comment: Just now I tried doing the same with an instance, where I simply stopped the instance(not the stop-hibernate), and upon subsequent restart, the UPTIME was always 0, so in this case, I can agree with you that OS was definitely NOT running, but in stop-hibernate, your "OS would might be running or as you said might be calculating uptime in a different way".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @John Rotenstein rightly said, its ***true OS is not running.***

1. The state of os at the time when the "*hibernate*" system call was issued, is stored on the disk.
2. Then when you restart the instance; the state from which it left off, is again loaded into memory.
3. SO effectively your system **never rebooted**.

**Uptime is measured from the time of boot - the OS isn't really booted during the time when you resume from hibernation - it's a restoration of a state, saved on the hard drive. That is why the uptime counter is increasing.**

*Therefore, uptime is not the best metric for determining the overall time the system has been ON but, rather, is a metric to tell when the last reboot was.*